# Write filter condition in StrongLoop with [and] and [or] conditions together

Tags: mysql, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying to filter data using "and" and "or" conditions. I would like to get this mySql query:

```
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE ((`property1`=11) OR (`property1`=13)) AND (`property2`=6)
```

The rest api filter that I wrote is like this:

```
filter[where][and][0][or][0][property1]=11&filter[where][and][0][or][1][propert‌​y1]=13&filter[where][and][1][property2]=6
```

I have an error like this:

```
ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column '[property1]' in 'where clause'
```

Why i have an error?

Comment: please give complete code snippts

Comment: @arjunkori my complete request uri is 
**http://localhost:4000/api/Datas/?filter[where][and][0][or][0][property1]=11&filter[where][and][0][or][1][propert‌​y1]=13&filter[where][and][1][property2]=6** 
I'm using get method about model Data and in the response i have an error **ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column '[property1]' in 'where clause'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model doesn't have `property1`. Please modify the filter according your data model

Comment: Thanks @EbrahimPasbani, but i have in my model Data the  [tag:property1], if i leave or condition in where filter everything is ok!

Comment: @J.Doe Try direct query without REST api please. If it's worked then maybe REST api query is not able to go deep

Comment: Thank you @Ebrahim, without REST api, working properly!